# Android - Loading images with a delay

Tags: java, android, imageview, handler, delay

I'm trying to fake some kind of progress bar. I have X images and want an `ImageView` to show them with a certain delay.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
for(i=2;i<X;i++) 
{
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  

              @Override
              public void run() {

               drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                                .getIdentifier("img_"+i, "drawable", getPackageName()));

               imgPayment.setImageDrawable(drawable);
               }}, DELAY);                  
}
```

But the for loop doesn't wait for the `run()` to end. I just see the first and last image. I tried a few other things but couldn't get the desired results.

Comment: Oh. Yes, this wont delay the for loop. It basically creates a task to run later. So you will be creating a set of tasks to run in the future, At the same time. What you really need to do, is invoke the next image get, from within the delay. So it will load one delayed, then when ran, will load the next one delayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using an Animation Drawable? It seems that you're not loading the images dynamically.

```
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    ...
 </animation-list>
```

Did I miss something?

[Link to the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

[Link to sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html)

As the sample docs state:

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the
>   AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of
>   your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached
>   to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without
>   requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the
>   onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity, which will get called
>   when Android brings your window into focus.

Comment: Good one... but I couldn't get it work until now. nothing happens, it just shows the first image...

Comment: alright, it's not allowed to start the animation in the `onCreate()`

Comment: you maybe could add the warning about the oncreate and the java code sample to your post... :)

Comment: There, I even found some doc pages that explain it further. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using `Thread.sleep()`? If you set sleeping interval of each image in an incremental manner, they will be displayed as if they are ordered.

```
for (i = 1; i < X; i++) 
{
    //Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Thread.sleep(i * 1000); // REMARK HERE!
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier
                                  ("img_" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
            imgPayment.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
    });
}
```

However, to be able to use the variable `i` as in the code above, declare it as a global static variable.

```
static int i = 0;
```

Comment: This will not work. You will be sleeping the new thread, not the for loop (UI Thread).

Comment: @Doomsknight of course with this code all the threads sleeps before they do their actual work. setting sleeping time different will make them appear in order. it's a simple logic. that's all.

Comment: Your absolutely right! I didnt notice the `i *`. (Sorry) I thought you were just sleeping instead of the delay variable. This will indeed stagger the delay :) +1

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an ASyncTask and then update your drawable from there or using a callback.